# Opening IFTTT app from another app using URL scheme giving me error in swift 4

Tags: swift, ifttt

I need to open IFTTT app from one of my app on a button click. Here is the code I am using to open the IFTTT app:

```
let appURL = NSURL(string: "https://ifttt.com/")
self.openURL(url: appURL as! NSURL)
```

This code (code used to open app with URL scheme that usually opens up other apps successfully) opens up IFTTT app but app opens up a different page. It is not home page of IFTTT app. I want to open the app's home page.

Any Solution ?
How can I open the IFTTT app home page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :
The url need to be added the name of the App we want to open :

```
let appURL = NSURL(string: "https://ifttt.com/connect/YOURAPPNAME")
self.openURL(url: appURL as! NSURL)
```

In this case YOUR APP should be live on App Store.